# VimL: Get extra KB from function that outputs file size

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Right now I'm creating a plugin of sorts for Vim, it's meant to simply have all kinds of utility functions to put in your statusline, here's the link: https://github.com/Greduan/vim-usefulstatusline

Right now I have this function: https://github.com/Greduan/vim-usefulstatusline/blob/master/autoload/usefulstatusline_filesize.vim

It simply outputs the file size from bytes to megabytes. Now, currently if the file size reaches 1MB for example it outputs `1MB`, this is fine, but I would also like for it to output the amount of bytes or KB extra that it has.

From example, instead of outputting `1MB` it would output `1MB-367KB`, see what I mean? It would output the biggest size, and then the remainder of the size that follows it. It's hard to explain.

So how would I modify the current function(s) to output the size this way?

Thanks for your help! Any of it is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who needs this? I doubt it would be convenient to anyone (especially when having small remainders like 1MB + 3KB), using 1.367MB is much better. I see in your code that you don’t have either MB (1000*1000 B) or MiB (1024*1024 B), 1000*1024 bytes is *very* strange. Also, don’t use `getfsize`, it is wrong for any non-file buffer you constantly see in plugins. Use `line2byte(line('$')+1)-1`.

For 1.367MB you can just rewrite [`humanize_bytes`](https://github.com/ZyX-I/powerline/blob/c7d3e98f2e17a81c7461e7048e37818174997ed6/powerline/lib/humanize_bytes.py) function in VimL if you are fine with depending on `+float` feature.

Using integer arithmetic you can get the remainder with

```
let kbytes_remainder = kbytes % 1000
```

And do change to either `MiB`/`KiB` (`M`/`K` is a common shortcut used in `ls`. *Without* `B`) or `MB`/`KB`.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I'll get working on this, I need to learn some Python in order to translate though. :)

Comment: Also, these newbie errors are probably because I'm still not very clear on byte sizes' names and stuff. I know a terabyte is 1000 gigabytes. :)

Comment: I fixed it I think, still gotta add this extra feature though. How does it look now? I learned some stuff from here BTW: http://pacoup.com/2009/05/26/kb-kb-kib-whats-up-with-that/

Comment: @Eduan It is wrong now. `1.3 MB` in your variant is lesser then `1.300 MB`. If you use remainder method to compute 1/1000, use `printf('%03u', kbytes_remainer)` (better `printf('%u.%03u', mbytes, kbytes_remainder)`) not to abuse positional notation.

Comment: Is it better now? I followed all your tips, great tips BTW. :) https://github.com/Greduan/vim-usefulstatusline/blob/master/autoload/usefulstatusline_filesize.vim